# Load The Class manually In Java when It has failed during the static block

Tags: java, classloader, noclassdeffounderror

I am using a external Library in my Project which I do not have any control over. I am using the jar. This external Library has a class on which I call the static method which makes the connection with some external system.

If there is a problem when connecting to the external System this external Library class throws a java.lang.exception.

Though I know it is a bad practice to use Throwable to catch the exception I used Throwable and caught the exception because I wanted to keep trying to connect the external application so I need to keep calling this external class method.

However when it failed for the first time Java internally unload this class. because when I call the method again java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class.

I need to know if there any way to load the class again.

I tried to load the class using java.lang.ClassLoader. however that did not work.

I used below article to load the class again
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/dynamic-class-loading-reloading.html

```
{
    ExternalClass.connect();
}catch(Throwable t)
{
     if(t instanceof java.lang.InternalError)
     {
        logger.error("Error While connecting", t);
     } 
     else{
    logger.error("Other Error While connecting", t);
     }
}
```

Comment: Java didn't _unload_ your class, it simply throws a `NoClassDefFoundError` if it failed to initialize when you attempt to re-initialize it. From what I remember, that class is still linked in the classloader.

Comment: I actually decompiled the class and if the class is not able to connect to device as sometime due to network the connection get broken it catch the connect exception however it explicitly throws java.lang.InternalError by warping the ConnectException. and If I tried to call the same code in the loop again to make the connection I get java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:

Comment: Clearly, the library you are using is not giving you a friendly way of notifying connection failure and retry mechanisms. If you can share the library/class details of how you are doing the connect, it may help invite alternative solutions.

Comment: “I used below article to load the class again …”—then everything is fine now?

Comment: No That did not work

Comment: Well, it might help to describe what you tried exactly and how it was failing. The linked article does already mention general limitations of reloading a class, so if these are already understood, we can avoid writing a redundant answer that wouldn’t help you.

Answer (score 0):

java.lang.InternalError is thrown when an unexpected,unexplained situation occurs in the JVM.
Your focus should be on finding out why the connect fails. Are you using the class in the right way?

The fact that the static method call fails on calling it a second time indicates the class is not consumed in the wight way. Do you need to perhaps setup some other variables , etc before calling the static method?